# Стоит ли сокращать число запросов на сервер

Tags: php, node.js, веб-сервер

Представим есть блог, есть какая-то страница блога, и на этой странице кидаются запросы на сервер(неожиданно, да? ). Запрос, допустим, на список постов, проверку на доступ юзера к этой странице и, допустим, кнопочки в сайдбаре. Всего 3 отдельных запроса. И что мне трижды кидать запросы на сервер из-за одной страницы? Думаю, как-то вместо трех запросов сделать один. Я могу сделать на сервере вместо 3 разных запросов один большой, который будет принадлежать не к отдельным кнопкам на странице, а выводить всю необходимую информацию для страницы за раз. Все равно лоадер не исчезнет, пока вся информация не подгрузится. Как делают в реальных проектах в таких случаях? Собирают информацию для страницы из нескольких разных запросов или для каждой страницы сделан свой запрос?

Comment: Если говорить о данных пользователя, то вы близки к тому, чтобы придумать [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/)

Comment: Для сокращения запросов при первой загрузке можно реализовать [SSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting)

Comment: Ещё смотрел [выступление](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_VgwsxuxXqE&t=6s), в котором докладчик предлагал сделать inline-стили для верхней части страницы (примерно 1000 пикселей). Это позволяло пользователю сразу увидеть контент, пока в нижней части страницы подгружались дополнительные данные

Comment: Ну, стоковые размеры блоков на вроде 1000 пикселей - это не круто. Для этих целей есть 100vh. Да и лучше не прятать недогруженную информацию, а потом просто подгрузить ее через React или типа того. SSR я примерно знаю, что это, а GraphQL впервые слышу. Можно в двух словах, что это?